# Нарушение прав доступа на чтение

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Есть 2 модуля(ассемблерный и си),необходимо подсчитать минимальный элемент массива,который я ввожу с помощью си функций и затем вызываю асм функцию,которая должна найти мин. элемент,проблема заключается в том,что во время выполнения программы,после ввода массива,программа вылетает с ошибкой(Нарушение прав доступа на чтение) и указывает на строку

```
mov ebx,[esi]
```

Этот код рабочий и выполнятся должен,так как выполняется аналогичный код

```
mov eax, [esi]
```

При чем,даже если заменить ebx на eax,программа все равно вылетает,за пределы массива я не выхожу,ничего запретного не делаю,просто в этом месте вылетает программа.Я не знаю что делать,так как код правильный,а программа не работает,пробовал пересоздать проект(в настройках указывал все правильно,другие программы работают хорошо).

Ассемблерный модуль:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.DATA
.CODE
MAS_FUNC PROC C mas:dword, n:dword
xor eax,eax
xor ebx,ebx


mov esi,mas
mov eax, [esi]
mov ecx,n

cycle:
mov ebx,[esi] ;тут вылетает
cmp eax,ebx ;тут тоже вылетает,даже если удалил пред строку и добавил
          ;[esi] 


jg metka
continue:
add esi,4
loop cycle


metka:
mov eax,[esi]
jmp continue


ret
MAS_FUNC ENDP
END
```

Си модуль:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" int MAS_FUNC(int *, int);
int main() {
int *mas, n, k;
system("chcp 1251");
system("cls");
cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
cin >> n;
mas = new int[n];
cout << "Введите элементы массива: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    cout << "mas[" << i << "]= ";
    cin >> mas[i];
}
k = MAS_FUNC(mas, n);
cout << k;
cin.get(); cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что `mov esi,mas` помещает в esi первый элемент массива, а не адрес этого массива. может попробовать что то типа `mov esi, offset mas` или `lea esi, mas`.

Comment: @Mike если я пишу mov eax,[esi+4],все корректно выполняется и берется первый элемент массива,если [esi+8]-второй,все правильно заносится

Comment: Тогда вам в asm коде стоило бы показать как объявлены `mas` и `n`. А то ведь не ясно mas это первый элемент или переменная содержащая адрес первого элемента (т.е. указатель)

Comment: @Mike mas-это указатель,в примере,с которого я переделывал,так работало,доступ осуществлялся именно таким образом

Comment: Еще мне не нравится конструкция `add esi,4; loop cycle` и особенно сразу за ней `mov eax,[esi]` на последнем шаге цикла, когда уже n кончилось у вас esi увеличивается и начинает указывать за пределы массива после чего происходит переход к mov. Вообще вам бы в отладчике походить по этому коду, оно так надежнее, чем на текст смотреть

Comment: тут не нужен отладчик,я вижу на каком месте вылетает,до этого ничего толком не выполняется и не изменяется,моя программа даже не успевает на метку перепрыгнуть,так как первая команда цикла даже не выполняется

Comment: А в ecx при этом уже содержится `n` и оно корректно (это я к тому, может у вас не эта строка не работает. а предыдущая. И как вы кстати по той картинке, что привели в вопросе поняли, что проблема возникает на первой итерации цикла. Может она гораздо позже происходит, когда esi уже ушло далеко вперед. явно не хватает в вопросе содержимого всех регистров на момент ошибки